# How to make non c# cshtml changes and see results WITHOUT recompiling?

Tags: visual-studio, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-debugging

Now that I'm on the latest and greatest version of everything, I found that my cshtml changes weren't being recognized until I stopped and restarted my application. Okay, no problem... I figured it out. I just had to enable the feature to allow Visual Studio to recompile my changes. Cool.

Well... not cool. Because it takes forever. Huge time waster. Before this, I could make all the cshtml changes I wanted and the results showed up just fine.

Any way to go back to how it was before? I honestly don't remember if C# code changes could be made and observed without recompiling before (I thought so, but maybe not). But I sure as heck know I didn't have to recompile to see my html/css/js changes. And I try to write as little C# in my views as possible... the vast majority of the changes I make are html/css/js.

When I need to be able to quickly hit F5 over and over in my browser to see tiny style changes until I get the page looking just right, this can literally eat up more than an hour of my life every day.

There must be a way to fix this?!

EDIT:

After writing this I realized that I was not experiencing this behavior in another .NET 5.0 solution. At the time, it was still very slow in the solution in question though. Just now I tried @PerryQian-MSFT's suggestion and it *seemed* to work like a charm... however I can't say whether it was actually this that resolved the issue or not as I then undid the change and it now still works quickly.

I may have applied an update to Visual Studio 2019 in the interim and there's an off chance they improved something, but I know that's unlikely. So not really sure whether applying Perry's steps triggered something that resolved the issue or whether it would have worked fine today had I not made any changes whatsoever.

Comment: Any update about this issue?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Thanks for checking up... my reply is a little long so I added it as an edit to the post.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It might be a XY issue from your description. Since you have a conclusion for this issue, it is better for you to change your conclusion as an answer and then mark it:)

Answer (score 5):

**CShtml** file with asp net core projects is special and it cannot get the new changes when you modify the pages under debug process by default.

You have to do some changes to your project additionally and then you can get it:

**1)** install the nuget package called [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation).

If your project targets to `net 5.0`, you have to install the nuget version `5.0.x`, if it targets to `net core 3.1`, you have to install the nuget version `3.1.x`.

**2)** add `services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();` under **ConfigureServices** method from `Startup.cs` file.

**Then**, start debugging your project, make changes to cshtml file,(not stop debugging) refresh the browser page and you will get what you want.

Comment: No, sadly I won&#39;t &quot;get what I want&quot;. I literally said I want to see it update WITHOUT recompiling. I also capitalized that in the post. It takes too long when I make a change to see the result... like I have to wait around 10 seconds rather than the 1 or 2 seconds I was accustomed too. This is even in a new project I started that has almost no dependencies. It is absolutely ridiculous.

Comment: No offense to you,  I appreciate you trying to help. I just realize that there is no way to "fix" this now because apparently this was part of them trying to get away from Rosylen or something like that so there is no way to get the old functionality back because it's just gone.  I can only hope they improve the performance is future versions. :(

Comment: To disable the recompiling, please right-click on the solution-->`Properties`-->`Configuration Properties`-->`Configuration`-->uncheck the `Build` of the project.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow... I hope this is a solution that will allow the website to update any html/css/javascript changes. But if it reverts to the behavior where it simply continues to show the last version of the page since the most recent compilation then that will obviously defeat the purpose. Got my fingers crossed though...

Comment: Hope your any feedback.

Comment: Point #1 is key, re: the default Nuget package targets .net 6.0 as of Feb-2022, so you have to use the Version picker to install the latest 5.x version to target .net 5.0.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at all if you're editing non-razor tags like for instance updating some inline javascript. Still have to stop solution, rebuild, restart to see changes.